# Adjusting dates and eliminating overlaps in SQL query for a table with start and end dates

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

I'm having trouble constructing an SQL query to adjust dates in a table. I have the following table called "table_main":

| start_date | end_date | name | rate | id_sup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 | name1 | 1 | SUP1 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 | name6 | 32 | SUP3 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 | name3 | 15 | SUP2 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 | name4 | 54 | SUP2 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 | name5 | 43 | SUP1 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 | name6 | 64 | SUP1 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-15 | name6 | 43 | SUP1 |

**SCHEMA:**

start_date  DATE    NULLABLE
end_date    DATE    NULLABLE
name            STRING  NULLABLE
rate            FLOAT   NULLABLE
id_sup      STRING  NULLABLE

My goal is to adjust the dates in a way that eliminates any overlapping dates between the records while preserving the sequence of the start dates. I've used the following SQL query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE temp_table AS
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN t1.start_date <= t2.end_date THEN DATE_ADD(t2.end_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
        ELSE t1.start_date
    END AS start_date,
    t1.end_date,
    t1.industry,
    t1.exclusion_rate,
    t1.suppliers
FROM 
    table_main AS t1
LEFT JOIN 
    table_main AS t2
ON 
    t1.industry = t2.industry
    AND t1.suppliers = t2.suppliers
    AND t1.start_date <= t2.end_date
    AND t1.end_date >= t2.start_date
    AND (t1.start_date <> t2.start_date OR t1.end_date <> t2.end_date)
```

However, the resulting output contains incorrect start dates. For example, the resulting output looks like this(Changes should only occur where name and id_sup are equal to each other and there is an intersection in dates):

| start_date | end_date | name | rate | id_sup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 | name1 | 1 | SUP1 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 | name6 | 32 | SUP3 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 | name3 | 15 | SUP2 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 | name4 | 54 | SUP2 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 | name5 | 43 | SUP1 |
| 2022-01-16 | 2023-02-01 | name6 | 64 | SUP1 |
| **2023-02-02** | 2023-01-15 | name6 | 43 | SUP1 |

I would like to achieve the following result:

| start_date | end_date | name | rate | id_sup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 | name1 | 1 | SUP1 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 | name6 | 32 | SUP3 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 | name3 | 15 | SUP2 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 | name4 | 54 | SUP2 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 | name5 | 43 | SUP1 |
| 2022-01-16 | 2023-02-01 | name6 | 64 | SUP1 |
| **2022-01-01** | 2023-01-15 | name6 | 43 | SUP1 |

Can you help me figure out how to modify my SQL query to achieve the desired result? I would be very grateful for any help!